# Vuetify File Uploads

Tags: html, vue.js, file-upload, vuetify.js

I'm trying to upload a file in Vue.js using vuetify and then save the uploaded file in my data object.

HTML:

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" @change="onFileChange">
```

In my methods I call:

```
onFileChange(e) {

  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return;
  }   
  this.editedPerson.id_file = e.target.files[0].name;
},
```

This works 100%.

I do, however, want to use the Vuetify component:

```
<v-btn color="blue-grey" class="white--text" @click.native="openFileDialog">Upload<v-icon right dark>cloud_upload</v-icon></v-btn>
```

I hide the original file input tag but on this v-btn component I call the following method:

```
openFileDialog() {
  document.getElementById('file-upload').click();
},
```

So when I click on the v-btn component it simulates a click on the hidden file input tag and I can choose a file.

On change of the input tag I can still console.log the uploaded file but

```
this.editedPerson.id_file = e.target.files[0].name;
```

no longer works.

Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: this is a small upload component that I built for my project. See if this will help you: [Vuetify Upload Component](https://github.com/avrtau/vuetify_upload_component)

Answer (score 5):

This following code works fine for me. I've used axois for HTTPClient you might choose anything

```
<div id="app">
   <v-btn color="blue-grey" class="black--text" @click.native="openFileDialog">
    Upload
    <v-icon right dark> cloud_upload</v-icon>
   </v-btn>
   <input type="file" id="file-upload" style="display:none" @change="onFileChange">
</div> 


Vue.use(Vuetify);
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        formData: new FormData(),
    },
    methods: {
        openFileDialog() {
            document.getElementById('file-upload').click();
        },
        onFileChange(e) {
            var self = this;
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;       
            if(files.length > 0){
                for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
                    self.formData.append("file", files[i], files[i].name);
                }
            }   
        },
        uploadFile() {
            var self = this; 
            axios.post('URL', self.formData).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.
Front end: vue + vuetifyjs + typescript

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-file-input multiple label="File input" @change="selectFile"></v-file-input>
    <v-btn @click="upload">Upload</v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Axios from 'axios'

@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class LogDecode extends Vue {
  currentFile = ''

  selectFile (file: any): void {
    this.currentFile = file[0]
  }

  upload (): void {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', this.currentFile)

    Axios.post('/upload', formData)
      .then(response => {
        console.log({ response })
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log({ error })
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Server side: Golang + Gin

```
func uploadFile(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Println("upload...")
    file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "Bad request")
        return
    }

    filename := header.Filename
    fmt.Println(file, err, filename)
    
    out, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer out.Close()
    
    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    c.String(http.StatusCreated, "upload successful \n")
}
```