# File Upload using vuetify 2 v-file-input and axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

First of all, i've checked questions [file-upload-in-vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989162/file-upload-in-vuetify) and [vuetify-file-uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645358/vuetify-file-uploads). But the solutions there didn't work.

I'm trying to use vuetify 2 `<v-file-input>` to send multiple PDF files. I created the `FormData` object and appended all my files but when i attempt to submit it doesn't reach my backend. I just get an empty object. this is my code:

Template:

```
<v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <v-file-input show-size counter chips multiple label="Arquivo Geral" ref="myfile" v-model="files"></v-file-input>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex>
      <v-btn color="primary" text @click="submitFiles">test</v-btn>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

script:

```
data() {
    return {
        files: null,
    }
}
methods: {
    submitFiles(){
        let formData = new FormData()

        if(this.files){

            for( let file in this.files){
                formData.append("cave", file)
            }

            console.log(formData.getAll("cave"))
            console.log(this.files)
            axios.post('https://eniwp6w65oc77.x.pipedream.net/', 
                        {
                            files: formData,
                            test: "test"
                        }, 
                        { 
                            headers: { 
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            } 
                        }).then( response => {
                            console.log('Success!')
                            console.log({response})
                        }).catch(error => {
                            console.log({error})
                        })
        }
        else {
            console.log('there are no files.')
        }
    }
}
```

my response body and header in requestbin:

body:

```
{
    "files": {},
    "test": "test"
}
```

header:

```
host: eniwp6w65oc77.x.pipedream.net
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,gl;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 28
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Can you show your backend

Comment: hi @MarcelusTrojahn , the main problem is my formData object, in "files" key, arrives empty in my requestbin link. whats causing this i don't know. I suspect the problem could be in the request or how i am making my formData object. The request in client-side is my axios post request in "scripts" code. I added the missing request header on server-side.

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol i've been using requestbin to test my response. I updated with both header and body now

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, you have two bugs in code:

1. Where you're preparing `FormData` object. You can't use [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop for iterating an array of files here since `for-in` loops over enumerable property names of an object. You can use [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead.
2. You're using `formData` in brackets. You should pass `FormData` instance, not JSON. To send aditional paramaters like `"test"` using `FormData` do `formData.append("test", "foo bar")`

Also check that your backend properly handles `multipart/form-data` data. If your backend is in `Node.js` and `Express.js` then you should use proper body parser middleware, for example [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Here is a working example:

Node.js/Express.js backend:

```
const multer = require("multer"),
...    
router.post("/upload-files", multer().array("files"), function (req, res) {
    console.log("body: ", req.body);
    console.log("files:", req.files);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

frontend:

```
submitFiles() {
    if (this.files) {
        let formData = new FormData();

        // files
        for (let file of this.files) {
            formData.append("files", file, file.name);
        }

        // additional data
        formData.append("test", "foo bar");

        axios
            .post("/upload-files", formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("Success!");
                console.log({ response });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log({ error });
            });
    } else {
        console.log("there are no files.");
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to set `Content-Type` header manually when you pass `FormData` as a `POST` request body

Comment: thanks! i changed fo...in to for...of. But it still doesnt :( i must be missing something

Comment: @MarcelusTrojahn, `axios.post(url, formData)` works fine. `formData` should be an instance of FormData, not a plain JSON. I think the problem is with your backend. Could you provide your backend code?

Comment: figured it out. I was using formData between brackets in my body request. In the end my code had 2 errors. The For..in and formData between brackets. Your example works fine. Thanks Yurii

Comment: The formData javascript object was the key to make it work, thank you so much!