# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to upload a photo with `Vuetify`, `Laravel` and `Axios`

I want to click on the upload button so `Axios`'s `post` method   sends the selected file to the server

`v-file` input:

```html
<v-file-input :rules="rules"
    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
    placeholder=" تغیر تصویر پروفایل"
    v-model="files"
    prepend-icon="mdi-camera">
</v-file-input>
```

`v-btn`:

```html
<v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark small color="deep-purple" @click="updateProfile">
    <v-icon dark>mdi-cloud-upload</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Data:

```js
data() {
    return {
        rules: [
            value => !value || value.size < 2000000 || 'حجم عکس بسیار زیاد است !',
        ],
        profile:[],
        fieldName:'',
        files:[]
    }
},
```

`Upload Method`

```js
updateProfile: () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',this.files);
    axios.post('/api/user/avatar/'+localStorage.getItem('id'), formData).then(res => {
        this.Change_Pic(res.data.src)
    }).catch(err => {});
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File Upload using vuetify 2 v-file-input and axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773556/file-upload-using-vuetify-2-v-file-input-and-axios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because of how to define the upload function, with change the upload function  the problem solved!

Code changed from :

```
updateProfile: () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',this.files);
    axios.post('/api/user/avatar/'+localStorage.getItem('id'), formData).then(res => {
        this.Change_Pic(res.data.src)
    }).catch(err => {});
},
```

To :

```
updateProfile: function() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',this.files);
    axios.post('/api/user/avatar/'+localStorage.getItem('id'), formData).then(res => {
        this.Change_Pic(res.data.src)
    }).catch(err => {});
},
```